# Anime movie about a boy in a ghost town

Tags: story-identification, anime, ghost

I saw this movies in the 2000s. I don't know when it came out. This is a kids movie!

It is about a boy who goes to a ghost town. He goes to some bar and meets a little fire spirit that follows him around. While in the town, he stops at a store. The store owners come out from the back room. It is a man and a woman. When the boy leaves, they go back to the back room where their skin comes off and they are skeletons. This not a gruesome scene. Their skin is like a drape. They were wearing funny headdresses. So there is a parade going on down the street. A beautiful cage is being carried down the street. Inside is a girl, who the boy falls in love with. The boy follows the girl. There is another girl floating in the sky. She has a bat cellphone. The boy follows the girl to a place where a woman in a giant clam shell sits. She tries to inhale the boy to steal his youth, but the girl stops the woman and the woman starts to crack like a mirror. The girl and boy escape. The girl is a ghost so she can't go out in the sunlight. She hides in an umbrella/parasol because she can fit in tiny spaces.

I don't remember what happens next. I know there is a big guy with a hammer who gets turned into a baby at the end of the movie. There is also a ghost train. The train is heading for big golden gates. I also don't remember how the movie ends.

(It's been years since I've seen the movie and I don't remember the title of it.)

The boy has brown/black hair but you barely see it because of the hat he is wearing. The hat is not like a normal hat. It has two rounded sections on both sides and is like a tan-ish green color. This movie does not take place in the present time. It takes place in a time maybe before the 1800s. The girl is very pretty and elegant. She has an anime geisha down hair-do but her hair is also up a little by using chopsticks (sorry if i called it the wrong thing).

Please help me find out what this movie is!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're probably looking for [*A Chinese Ghost Story: The Tsui Hark Animation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Chinese_Ghost_Story:_The_Tsui_Hark_Animation), a 1997 animated film from Hong Kong.

The story is about a about a young, tax collector named Ning wandering through China with his dog, after being dumped by the girl of his dreams over another man. The story is based on *[The Enchanting Shadow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enchanting_Shadow),* a supernatural romance movie by [Li Han-hsiang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Han-hsiang).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That is exactly the movie I was thinking of!!! You Krazer are amazing!!!!!!